# What is the maximum score value for lingo algorithm?

Tags: carrot2

I want to produce a word cloud of the cluster results, but to do that, I will need to know the maximum score value that the Lingo algorithm has. Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no upper bound on the scores produced by Lingo. One workaround may be normalizing the scores to the 0..1 scale before display.

On a more general note, some disadvantage of using the scores for display purposes is that they do not directly translate to a tangible property of the cluster. The only meaning attached to the score is along the lines of: "the higher the score, the better the cluster Lingo *thinks* is". As an alternative to scores, you may want to use the size of the cluster (number of documents assigned to the cluster).